# How to change kendo UI listview control Paging Name at bottom

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

How to change kendo UI listview control Paging Name at bottom

as it shows "items" by default I want to change it to "Symptoms"

$("#pager").kendoPager({
                message: {
                items:"Symptoms"
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

**Razor:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView(Model)
    .Name("listView")
    .Pageable(p => p.Messages(m => m.Display("Symptoms {0}-{1} to {2}"))
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#pager").kendoPager({
     messages: {
         display: "{0} - {1} of {2} symptoms"
         }
});
```

Comment: I have tried in this manner  $("#pager").kendoPager({
                message: {
                items:"Symptoms"
            }

Comment: Check my Javascript answer now, I'm sure it will work